# pass a list as argument of the func1d in numpy.apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I don't manage to pass a list as arguments to func1d in numply.apply_along_axis(...).

```
def test(a, value):
    print(value)
    return a

a = np.zeros((49), dtype=list) 
kwargs = {"value":[1,1,1]}
zep = np.vectorize(test)
np.apply_along_axis(zep, 0, a, **kwargs)
```

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/ibpc/osx/lbt/numpy/1.9.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nump/lib/shape_base.py", line 91, in apply_along_axis
res = func1d(arr[tuple(i.tolist())], *args, **kwargs)
File "/ibpc/osx/lbt/numpy/1.9.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1700, in __call__
return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
File "/ibpc/osx/lbt/numpy/1.9.2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1769, in _vectorize_call
outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (49,) (3,)
```

So, He want that my len(kwargs["value"])==49. But it's not what I want. 
I need to change value if I want (during the numpy.apply_along_axis(func1d) I need to update my list).

How can I pass a list as argument? Or may be use another way to resolve this problem..

In real, I have a numpy.array of list of position in 3Dspace for a particle. 
Like this:

```
dim = [49,49,49]
dx = 3
origin = [3,3,3]
nb_iter = 5
ntoto=np.load("ntoto.npy")
ntoto = ntoto.flatten()
liste_particles=np.zeros((5), dtype=list)
for i in range(len(liste_particles)):
    liste_particles[i]=[[r.uniform(0,150),r.uniform(0,150),r.uniform(0,150)]]*nb_iter #nb_iter is just the number of iteration I want to do in calcTrajs. 
vtraj=np.vectorize(calcTrajs, otypes=[list])
np.apply_along_axis(vtraj, 0, liste_particules)
```

Here, I have five particles randomly place. Moreover, I have another numpy.array (shape==(49,49,49)) which contains a vector_field.

Here the func1d which I need to run:

```
def calcTrajs(a): 
    global ntoto, dim, dx, origin #ntoto is my vector_field
    for b in range(1,len(a)):
        ijk = s2g(a[b-1], dx, origin, dim) # function to have on which vector my particle is.(space to grid, because my vector_field is like a grid). 
        value = np.asarray(ntoto[flatten3Dto1D(ijk, dim[1], dim[2])]) # so value contains the vector who influence my particle. 
        try:
            a[b] = list(a[b-1] + value*1000)
        except:
            print("error")
            break 
     return a
```

this function permits me to launch a particle in my vector_field and calculate its trajectory. 
As you can see, I put global variables. But I want to pass this variables as arguments and not as global. ntoto is a numpy.array, dim is a list (dimension of my vector field), dx is the cell spacing (because my vector_field is in a grid which contains many cells and each cell contains a vector) and origin is the first point of my grid.

Best regards,

Adam

Comment: Neither `vectoriize` nor `apply...` will improve processing speed. I only recommend apply_along as an easier way to iterate when the array dimensions are >2.  Explain what you want with an example and plain iteration. No fancy stuff.

Comment: you say `He want that my len(kwargs["value"])==49.` and most be in that way, How do you do  `print(value)` for the 4th+ element?

Comment: What are you going to actually do in your `test` function? I feel like there should be much better ways to vectorize your function

Comment: Hello everybody, thanks to take time for my question, i update it to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, neither `vectorize` or `apply...` is a speed tool.  `vectorize` can be useful for broadcasting several arrays against each other.  `apply ...` can be useful for iterating over more than 2 dimensions.  With only one or two it is overkill.  Both are tools that beginners often misuse.

It looks like the `apply_along_axis` part is ok, though I haven't tested it.  The error lies in broadcasting in `vectorize`.

Especially since you are defining `a` as object dtype, you should specify like return dtype for `vectorize`.  Otherwise it performs a test calc to determine it.

```
In [223]: def test(a, value):
     ...:     print(value)
     ...:     return a
In [224]: zep = np.vectorize(test, otypes=['O'])
In [225]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5]])
In [226]: a
Out[226]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

`zep` works with `a` and a scalar

```
In [227]: zep(a,1)
1
1
Out[227]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

But when `a` has 2 items, and `value` as 3 items, I get the same sort of error as you did:

```
In [228]: zep(a,[1,2,3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-228-382aaa7a2dc6> in <module>()
----> 1 zep(a,[1,2,3])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2753             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   2754 
-> 2755         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   2756 
   2757     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2829                       for a in args]
   2830 
-> 2831             outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
   2832 
   2833             if ufunc.nout == 1:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

(2,) and (2,) is fine:

```
In [229]: zep(a,['a','b'])
a
b
Out[229]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

So is (2,) with (2,1), producing a (2,2) output.  This is an example of the kind of broadcasting where `vectoring` can help.

```
In [230]: zep(a,[['a'],['b']])
a
a
b
b
Out[230]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5])],
       [list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks you for you're help and advice. I update my question. I add a part with my real code.